# Apply android Selector for a specific child of listview and disable the selector on the other childs in the same list item

Tags: android, listview, selector

I have a list view with items that hold 2 views each(this `ListView` looks like a `GridView` with 2 columns).
I needed the header and the footer and they are not available in the `GridView`, so I turned to using list view.

I want a selector for individual child view of each list item, the list selector did not work, it applies the selector to both child views.

What I have tried so far ????

I make the root view of each single element a `FrameLayout` and I use the `android:foreground="@drawable/some_selector"` attribute so I can simulate the `drawSelectorOnTop` attribute.

My Problem :

How can I apply the selector only to the pressed child in the **listview item**.

list view layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/episode_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/black"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        android:listSelector="@null"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

episode item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="@drawable/all_show_cell_background_selector" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/llEpisode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#282828"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/episodeImage"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/video_blank" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/episodeDuration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/episodeImage"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/episodeImage"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="11sp" />
        <!-- android:textColor="#b5b4b4" -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/episodeTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/episodeImage"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="hdgsagafasfsdafsdfsdfasddfsad"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14sp" >

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showName"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/episodeTitle"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="hdgsagafasfsdafsdfsdfasddfsad"
            android:textColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:textSize="13sp" >

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/noOfViewsText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/showName"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="@string/number_of_views_text"
            android:textColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:textSize="11sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/episodeNumberOfViews"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/noOfViewsText"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/noOfViewsText"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fav_img"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="fsdafasdfsad"
            android:textColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:textSize="11sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fav_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/episodeNumberOfViews"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/favourite_title_show"
            android:src="@drawable/fav_episode" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

the single list item contains 2 episode items

this is the container that holds the 2 episode items

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- This container to help emulate a GridView in each ListView item -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you add a snapshot of the list item.. so that we have better chances of hitting the bulls eye.. Now we are blindfolded..

Comment: You do not need the framelayout.. set the selector to the relativeLayout

Comment: i want to draw the selector on the top so i use the framelayout and use the foreground as a selector

Comment: So now what is the behaviour?

Comment: nothing appeared but when i remove the listSelector, the foreground selector on the framelayout appear but on the both episode item i.e all epiosde on the list item :(

Comment: do you have `onItemClickListener` set? if so remove it..

Comment: no there is no onItemClickListener on the listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I face this problem before , and have a nice solution look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723015/draw-selector-on-top-for-a-basic-linear-layout/13135973#13135973) for sample code

Answer (score 4):

Im not really sure about foreground but what i actually do is use a listview. then in the adapter i set two relative layouts for every row in the list, here is my list attributes:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/seccion_list"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
```

in my adapter i set the layout to load for every row, here is the first relative layout for the first frame in the row:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/primerContenedor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/seccion_3_imagen_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" 
        android:background="@drawable/layout_selector">
```

so bassically what i do is to set the relative layout clickable and focusable attributes true and define a selector:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/blue"/> 
    <item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@color/blue"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/grey" /> 
</selector>
```

Comment: Ya i tried you solution by adding clickable and focusable attributes to my relativeLayout then it works. Thanks you

Comment: I only needed clickable and pressed, seems listview is taking away the click or something .... anyways put clickable on each child within your listview.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `@android:listSelector="@null"` for your listview. Then set selectors for the individual child views of list item.

Also set `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"` on the list item and set `android:duplicateParentState="false"` on the episode item.

Comment: try `android:duplicateParentState="false"` on the episode item root

Comment: @userSeven7s What do you mean episode item? Can you help me ?

Comment: @null would set default selector it should be set to transparent

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a ListView Adapter, in which you inflate a custom layout holding two FrameLayouts with different ids for the left and right layouts. If not - this is one solution.

Inside the ListView Adapter, add a global int selectedRowId = -1 and short leftRight = -1 (0 means left, 1 means right). In your getView method, when constructing the convertView, check if postition==selectedRowId. If yes - check if left is 0 or 1, which give you your selected item and you can manipulate it.
Then add an onClickListener to each FrameLayout , in which store selectedRowId = position, leftRight = 0 or 1 based on the selection and call notifyDataSetChanged().