# Ripple effect over a RecyclerView item containing ImageView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ripple

I have a `RecyclerView` that expands the following grid item :

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/children_tile_border"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/children_tile_border"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

        <com.example.app.ui.widget.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/child_picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:background="@color/tile_text_background"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            ..............
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But the ripple effect doesn't appear unless I set the `SquareImageView's` visibility to invisible. It seems the ripple effect is drawn below the `SquareImageView`. How can I can I make it drawn over the `SquareImageView`?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

add below code to your parent layout

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

if you want custom ripple effect add this ripple_custom.xml in your drawable-v21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorHighlight">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@color/windowBackground" />
</ripple>
```

to support older version add ripple_custom.xml in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorHighlight" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: not working for me. I have a RelativeLayout item root with the above configurations : http://pastebin.com/fy3RcfCm, using android support library v23

Comment: Is it working for you on all devices. I tried setting                 android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" to layout inside RecyclerView but it not works

Comment: @Sagar Trehan some times in your child of parent will take click event i think that's the issue

Comment: @Jinu I have a ImageView along with other views in item of ListView. When I gave above selector to ImageView ripple effect works but it does not appear because ImageView content is covering selector. For solving this I wrapped ImageView inside a RelativeLayout and add one more view in it covering width and height of ImageView in z order. I gave click event to this view and selector background. Applying these changes ripple effect appear correctly. But I dont want to introduce a new View doing this. Please suggest

Answer (score 13):

Change:

```
android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
```

To:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

And add this to your SquareImageView

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Comment: This one actually worked for me. I think that this is the best solution when the core view of the recyclerview item is an ImageView.

Answer (score 9):

We can wrap RecyclerView Item inside `FrameLayout` and set `android:foreground` property to it. Checkout following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723015/draw-selector-on-top-for-a-basic-linear-layout) for details. It works for me pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a CardView + ImageView 
just insert in CardView

```
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

And for RelativeLayout + ImageView 
Insert in RelativeLayout

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Or

```
android:focusable="true"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

This codes worked for me

Comment: what if constraint layout and imageview!

Answer (score 1):

Your `SquareImageView` is filling up the entire space (`width` is `match_parent` and `height` is `wrap_content`) and so the `SquareImageView` receives the click event.

What worked in my case was setting the clickable state of all objects in your `RelativeLayout` to false:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Just make sure your `RelativeLayout` handles the click event in your activity. In my code I set the `RelativeLayout` to a `view v` and set an `onClick Listener` on it to handle the `CheckBox` within my List item.

```
v.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Hopefully this helps anyone who reads it.

Answer (score 1):

Above answers are correct. but I want to recommend the usage of android:foreground instead as it shows the ripple infront of the imageView.

On your root view, add the following.

```
android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_effect_color_primary"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

I know it's a pretty late answer to such old thread. But who knows, someone might actually find it useful.